# Flutter: Error in syncfusion slider while applying theme

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, syncfusion

I am implementing a SFSlider in my app. When I try to give a theme to the slider using SfTheme, I get an error:

```
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderSlider#850b3 relayoutBoundary=up7 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

My code is :

```
 Container(
          height: constraints.maxHeight*0.1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            child: SfTheme(
              data: SfThemeData(
                  sliderThemeData: SfSliderThemeData(
                      activeLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      inactiveLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),

                  )
              ),
              child: SfSlider(activeColor: Colors.green,
                inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                min: 0.0,
                max: 100.0,
                value: _value,
                interval: 25,
                showTicks: true,
                showLabels: true,
                enableTooltip: true,
                minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
                onChanged: (dynamic value) async {
                  totalAmount = await calculateData();
                  totalAmount = totalAmount.ceil() + 0.0;
                  setState(() {
                    _value = value;
                    total_amount_display = totalAmount;
                  });
                },
              ),),),),
```

The Container is inside a column, which in turn is inside a container in dialog box.

When I remove the theme, the slider is rendered perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome this issue by setting color and **fontSize** when setting the text style for the active and inactive labels in **SfSliderThemeData**.

```
SfTheme( 
   data: SfThemeData(
     sliderThemeData: SfSliderThemeData(
         activeLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14),
         inactiveLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14),
     )
   ),
)
```

If you like to set the color alone for the label,then you can use the [textTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)’s text style values retrieved from context’s [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) and using the [copyWith()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/copyWith.html) method to set the desired color.

```
final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);

SfTheme(
    data: SfThemeData(
         sliderThemeData: SfSliderThemeData(
            activeLabelStyle: themeData.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(color: Colors.red),
            inactiveLabelStyle: themeData.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(color: Colors.red),
         )
    ),
)
```

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/i4007071991344175