# Does SfSliderTheme still exist in syncfusion_flutter_slider?

Tags: flutter, widget, themes, syncfusion

I saw some on internet use 'SfSliderTheme' in order to customize 'SfSlider'.
So, I tried to use it, but I can't use it and IDE said
"The method 'SfSliderTheme' isn't defined for the type '**Screen'.".
[can't use SfSliderTheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDJOx.png)

Example usage:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73464300/flutter-error-in-syncfusion-slider-while-applying-theme

Website where it says you can use 'SfSliderTheme' to customize SfSlider.
[https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/latest/sliders/SfSlider-class.html#:~:text=Slider%20can%20be%20customized%20using%20the%20SfSliderTheme](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/latest/sliders/SfSlider-class.html#:%7E:text=Slider%20can%20be%20customized%20using%20the%20SfSliderTheme)

Hope someone can fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you haven’t imported a theme package from syncfusion_flutter_core in your project. To resolve this issue, we recommend importing the following package into your project.

Code snippet:

```dart
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_core/theme.dart';
```

Comment: woking!
add syncfusion_flutter_core: ^xxx -> to your projects pubspec.yaml